# How do you clear a vector of strings in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, matrix

Using a global variable like:

```
params_vector[100][100] = {};
```

Is it possible to 'reset' or 'clear' the values inside this array just to be equal as from when it's initialized? There are a lot of examples with `char *arg[]` (which `arg[i] = NULL` works) but none with a 'matrix' like this.

Comment: It is not a *vector* of strings.It is an array of arrays.

Comment: Thanks!!! I wasn't sure which one was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a multidimensional array of `char`, you can "reset" it simply by calling

```
#include <string.h>

memset(params_vector, 0, sizeof params_vector);
```

If you just need to set the *first* byte of each string to 0, using a `for` loop could be more efficient.

Comment: I used a for with params_vector[i] on the first parameter and inside the sizeof too. I didn't know it would work too. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is a multidimensional array of `char`'s, e.g.

```
char params_vector[N][M];
```

for some value of N and M - you *don't* need to `memset()` the *entire* thing to '\0'; it's enough to set the first character of each string to '\0':

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    params_vector[i][0] = '\0';
}
```

However, if `N` is small, this optimization might not be worth it and a

```
memset(params_vector, '\0', M * N);
```

would be fine.

Comment: Isn't the '\0' a termination for NUL with one 'L'? And the ideal is to reset so it stays like NULL with double 'L'? Correct me if I'm wrong but is '\0' really the same as wanting to put as NULL?

Comment: '\0' is indeed also referred to as NUL. Its numeric value is 0. But - you don't use it for pointers. NULL is something you assign to pointers... and its numeric value is also 0 (on most  platforms anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Use [`memset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset):

```
memset(params_vector, 0, sizeof(params_vector));
```

Comment: You might want to explain why this works on most current architectures but is not fully portable if `params_vector` has non integral members.

Comment: @chqrlie: Since OP mentions "vector of strings" and `char * arg[]`, I think it is reasonable to assume he/she is talking about characters.

Comment: Yep, it was about characters! Thanks guys!

Comment: @Acorn: my bad, the title indeed mentions *vector of strings*, which makes *einpokulm*'s answer quite effective.

Comment: @chqrlie: No problem! :-) Indeed, einpokulm's's answer is perfect if one does not need to clear the entire memory but rather make the null-terminated strings zero-length. However, since OP asked about going back to the initialized state (`= {}`), then clearing the entire area would be needed.